# matrix vs. list - switching from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

Coming from a Matlab background, where everything is a matrix/vector, it was very easy to loop through a given data set and build a matrix successively. Since the final object was a matrix, it was also very easy to extract specific elements of the matrix. I'm finding it rather problematic in Python. I've reproduced the code here to explain where I am getting stuck.

1. The original data just a time series with a month and a price. The goal is to simulate select subsets of these prices. The loop starts by collecting all months into one set, and then drops one month in each successive loop. For 12 months, I will have (n^2  - n)/2 + n, 78 columns in total in this example. To be clear, the n is the total number of time periods; 12 in this data set. The rows of the matrix will be the Z scores sampled from the standard normal variable - the goal is to simulate all 78 prices in one go in a matrix. The # of z scores is determined by the variable num_terminal_values, currently set to 5 for just keeping things simple/easy to visualize at this point.
   Here's a link to a google sheet with the original matrix  [google sheet with corr mat](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xDLoIHNEuW11Qwh9MuXwQCHOgS9i216zKzh3QuQHi1s/edit?usp=sharing)  . The code below may not work from the google sheet; the sheet is intended to show what the original data is. My steps (and Python code) are as follows:

#1 read the data
dfCrv = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name = 'upload', usecols = range(0,2)).dropna(axis=0)

#2 create the looper variables and then loop through the data to build a matrix. The rows in the matrix are Z values sampled from the standard normal (this is the variable num_terminal_values). The columns refers to each individual simulation month.

```
import datetime as dt
lst_zUCorr = []

num_terminal_values = 5

as_of = dt.datetime(2020, 12, 1)
max_months = dfCrv.shape[0]
sim_months = pd.date_range(dfCrv['term'].iloc[0], dfCrv['term'].iloc[-1], freq='MS')
end_month = dfCrv['term'].iloc[-1]

dfCrv = dfCrv.set_index('term',drop=False)

for runNum in range(max_months):
    sim_month = dfCrv['term'].iloc[runNum]
    ttm = ((sim_month - as_of).days)/365
    num_months = (end_month.year - sim_month.year) * 12 + (end_month.month - sim_month.month) + 1
    zUCorr = npr.standard_normal(size=(num_terminal_values, num_months))        
    lst_zUCorr.append(zUCorr)
```

## investigate the objects

```
lst_zUCorr
z  = np.hstack(lst_zUCorr)
z
```

So far, everything works fine. However, I don't know how to transform the object lst_zUCorr to a simple matrix. I've tried hstack etc.; but this still doesn't look like a matrix.
The next set of operations require data in simple matrix form; but what I'm getting here isn't a matrix. Here's a visual:

Key point/question - the final 5x78 matrix in Matlab can be used to do more operations. Is there a way to convert the equivalent Python object into a 5x78 matrix, or will I now need to do more coding to access specific subsets of the Python objects?

[image: Code output in Python vs. Matlab]

Comment: Use NumPy. It’s syntax is inspired by MATLAB, though not identical. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Comment: Yeah, MATLAB code in python is best done with `numpy.array`. That will ensure stuff is quite similar to MATLAB